# WCF and storing authentication info

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, forms-authentication

Let I have some WCF service. What I need is to store additional data related to the authenticated user in order to get this info immediately (without querying it from data storage).
I'd like to know the best practices to accomplish it. I assume the following alternatives could be used:

1) Make the service AspnetCompatible and use Forms authentications, HttpContext and Cache. As regards this alternative, I'd like to know about the disadvantages of using it.

2) Make the service per-session (InstanceContextMode.PerSession). As for me, the main disadvantage of this option is that it might cause problems with scalability. And as far as I know basicHttpBinding doesn't support the per session mode(that is, it's not suitable in case of Silverlight apps).

So, what do you think about it and what would you recommend to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the username like this:

`OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name`

You can even get the password, though it's a bit more complicated. Rory Primrose [explains it in his article](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx).

What other information do you need and what's keeping you from storing it in memory between calls?

EDIT:

Scalibity is a valid concern, ideally I'd stick to PerCall instancing. A simple means of sharing information between calls is not any different from sharing information between instances in a non-WCF context - namely statics.

Comment: For example, Organization details the user is logged in as well as other specific data related to the authenticated user which will be frequently used. As for 'storing it in memory between calls' - it's to general answer, I need more concrete ;) (since I mentioned the ways I know in order to do it, but I'd like to know whether there are other and  better solutions

Comment: Do you mean using static dictionaries(since I need share the data not between all calls but between those which relate to the authenticated user)? If so, I will need to deal with cleanuping this data, but it may become a little bit complicated(except that case when the user was explicitly logged out)...