# WCF and UserName credentials when using basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, authentication

As far as I know, in order to use UserName credentials with basicHttpBinding to authenticate against the SQL Server membership provider, I need to set TransportWithMessageCredentials security mode. But recently I had a look at the [WCF Security guide](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/). And in this book I found the similar example, but instead of TransportWithMessageCredentials, Basic mode is used and  a custom HTTP module is created that will authenticate users.

I'm wondering which approach is worth using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches do the same but they use different approach. The first approach uses SOAP header to pass credentials whereas second approach uses HTTP header to pass credentials.

The second approach involves additional network roundtrip (handled internally by WCF) because first call is rejected with 401 status code and demanded Basic authentication and only second call contains the header with credentials. This is the way how HTTP authentication works and client should not send credentials until server requires them (even there is possibility to preauthenticate but I think WCF doesn't use it). The second approach cannot be used with streamed transfer mode.

There can be one additional difference between those two methods. The first approach authenticate each call whereas second approach authenticate connection so if you call the service multiple times from the same proxy (and the same connection) you will be authenticated only once with the second approach but for each call with the first approach.

Edit:

There is no preference between those two. You will use the one which is more suitable for your needs. If you have control over both client and server or if you know that client will use some more powerful SOAP stack the first one is easier to set up. If you don't have control over your clients and they can use different platforms you can find second more interoperable.

As a side note the first one works only with SOAP protocol whereas the second one works for SOAP, POX and REST (POX and REST require different binding).

Comment: So, as I understand, the first approach is preferred?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) BTW, could you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816652/wcf-and-storing-authentication-info?

Comment: In both cases, each call will be authenticated. Custom authentication code can be used with both approaches. Please refer it to use custom username/password authentication with message security http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/05/wcf-authentication-custom-username-and-password-validator.aspx